# Laravel site on live server permission issue

Tags: php, laravel

I uploaded my laravel 7 app on live server but when I run it I got this error:

**The stream or file "G:\PleskVhosts\alajamiaccounting.com\site\storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied**

I tried to change storage folder permission but still not fixing the issue, what should I do?

Comment: It means the ownership of the folder does not allow for changing said file for web server user (or console). You need to make sure that is fixed accordingly by ensuring write permissions are given to both users, or change ownership as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the system or user running the Laravel code was not able to write to the `laravel.log` file. Check that the user group running the code has permission to write to the storage file and that the storage file has the proper CHMOD permissions

`chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: I did it and it worked, but all my routes not working except the "/"?

Comment: @kingkongofgreenland If your routes are not working, try making sure ModRewrite is enabled on your server.

Comment: but I hosted my site on windows server